# How to structure methods together that are supposed to be executed consequtively in Obj-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a language quiz app to learn Obj-C and I am having a hard time understanding the proper way to structure such the information processing functions. So far:

I have a collection of spanish words and their definitions in a separate text file.
Here's the main parts of the code that I am having trouble implementing:

```
@implementation SGLDictionary

-(NSString*)makeStringFromFile:(NSString *)myFileName {
    //read file and save to *string

return string;
```

}

```
-(NSArray *)getContentFromString:(NSMutableString *)string {
     //Here the string is trimmed and deheadered so only the content is left and returned as an NSArray.
return Array;
```

}

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)makeDictionaryFromArray:(NSArray *)array{
    //make the array mutable and form it into a dictionary by looping over it
return spanishToEnglishDictionary;
```

}

How do you later initialize an instance of the SGLDictionary class and call the methods so they are executed on the instance one by one? I'm not sure how this works because I thought the methods that change data don't return any (they `return void`).

Comment: Are you asking how to call a method ? Not sure what it is you don't understand ? Have you split these three steps into separate methods ?

Comment: You can do this in a single method just write code in sequential order and it will work, if you have written please post code.

Comment: @CW0007007 Yea exactly, I am not sure how to call them naturally after its structured this way

Comment: Well just call the next method at the end of the current one..

Comment: Aren't the first two steps a single call to the Foundation API anyway?    Three steps does not mean three methods, so simply lump them all into a single method.  I would worry about the way you are representing the data on disk, more than how the methods look.

Comment: @trojanfoe is right, the first two can be performed in a single method, then for the last if you wanted it to be in a sperate method just pass the array i.e. [self formatArray:array]; ?

Comment: @trojanfoe something just feels a little off about a dictionary having a 'make myself' method. Shouldn't the thing that makes the dictionaries (like a function) be separate from it?

Comment: Not sure I understand; all classes "make themselves" and besides your code isn't part of the dictionary class.  I cannot see anything wrong with a single `readMyData` method that allocates and reads the dictionary.

Comment: @CW0007007 So I would just call it like `NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [alreadyInitializedDictionaryInstance makeMySelf]`?

Comment: At this stage I think it's best to attempt a solution and post code.  I am not about to go through every line of a possible implementation.  That's not what this site is about.

Comment: @ValentineBondar no ... You aren't calling the method on the myDict but rather on self. I assume you've called a method before ? Post some code to what you've done.

Comment: @trojanfoe Oh no no, theres the NSDictionary class and theres my SpanishEnglishDictionary class. I see there may have been confusion there.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry if my question was not clear before. Have a look at it now

Comment: So you've subclassed `NSDictionary`?  It's rarely necessary to do that given the vanilla `NSDictionary` seems to do what you want.

Comment: @trojanfoe I made a SpanishEnglishDictionary class. Did I subclass `NSDictionary` by doing that?

Comment: You tell me; I assumed by the name that it was a subclass.

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, no. I just made another class like "Person", this one is "SpanishEnglishDictionary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryFromFile:(NSString *)file
{
    return [self makeDictionaryFromArray:[self getContentFromString:[self makeStringFromFile:file]]];
}
```

Isn't it enough for your question?

You can invoke this method like

```
SGLDictionary *sgl      = [[SGLDictionray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionry *dic = [sgl dictionaryFromFile:file];
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I didn't know that you could use self like that to embed calls

Answer (score 0):

example : if u have a method like

```
-(BOOL)myInteger:(int)number1 andSecond:(int)number2;
```

then lemme explain what is happenening -

Method name - `myInteger` `andSecond` (Yes this is the full method name).
`-(BOOL)` this is your `RETURN TYPE`.

`(int)number1` -- This int is the type of FIRST parameter named - number1.
`(int)number2` -- This int is the type of SECOND parameter named - number2.

andSecond -- this is the continuation of the METHOD NAME.

and this is how u will call this method

```
 [self myInteger:4 andSecond:5];
```

I dont know if i understood ur question properly but i guess it helps

Comment: @CW0007007 Sorry if my question was not clear before. Have a look at it now